# Validação Condicional de SubModel MVC 4 C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

Estou com o seguinte problema (vou simplificar as classes para facilitar o entendimento):

```
public class Class1 {
    [Required]
    public int? Id_Estabelecimento { get; set; }
    public string Nm_Nome { get; set; }
}

public class Class2 {
    [Required]
    public int Id_Classe2 { get; set; }
    public int Tipo_Cadastro { get; set; }
    public Classe1 CLASSE1 { get; set; }
}
```

O problema é o seguinte:
Caso o Tipo_Cadastro seja 1, a CLASSE1 (e seus atributos) não deve ser Required, caso seja 2 a classe deve ser validada normalmente.

**OBS1:** Consigo fazer esse procedimento na Controller (usando ModelState Clear), mas queria fazer no Client Side com o jquery unobtrusive.

**OBS2:** Sei que envolve uma validação condicional. Já fiz uma validação condicional envolvendo dois atributos da mesma classe. Nesse caso estou querendo "invadir" os data annotations de outra classe.

Será que alguem já passou por algo assim?
Ou será que eu estou complicando as coisas?

Answer (score 1):

Está complicando sim. **Nunca** a validação pode ser diferente por causa da mudança do client.

Aliás, limpar o `ModelState` é uma má prática em quase todos os casos.

Implemente sua `Class2` da seguinte forma:

```
public class Class2 : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public int Class2Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TipoCadastro { get; set; }

    public virtual Classe1 Classe1 { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) 
    { 
        if (TipoCadastro == 1) { 
            // Coloque a validação aqui. Dando erro, retorne um ValidationResult.
            yield return new ValidationResult("Campos tal e tal são obrigatórios.");
        }
    }
}
```

Pra indicar um determinado campo, acrescente um `array` de `String`s ao final, indicando pra quais campos a mensagem abrange:

```
yield return new ValidationResult("Campo Nome é obrigatório.", new string[] { "Nome" });
```

Comment: Não to conseguindo validação no client-side. Utilizando o @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.TipoCadastro) nada retorna. O campo aceita qualquer dado e parece que não faz nenhuma validação. Teria algo mais a fazer além dos acima?

Comment: @Felipe Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Agradeço a atenção. Ainda não consegui validação no client-side. Pode me esclarecer se 1 - O `public IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` vai dentro da Classe2 ? 2 - O que vai no lugar do _//Coloque a validação aqui.._? 3 - O  `ValidationMessageFor` é no TipoCadastro mesmo? e 4 - Preciso de algum codigo no js para o unobtrusive funcionar?  (Estou procurando em vários forums que indicam o mesmo que vc, mas não funciona, acho que estou pulando algum passo). Valew, mano!

Comment: 1 - O `public IEnumerable<ValidationResult>` vai dentro da classe que vai ser validada; 2 - Esse comentário é só pra indicar que naquele pedaço você vai ter que escrever sua validação. Não conheço suas regras de negócio; 3 - O `ValidationMessageFor` é o Helper que gera o objeto da `View` adequado para exibir mensagens de validação; 4 - Tem vários tutoriais sobre o unobstrusive... podem ser várias coisas faltando. Sugiro você ir abrindo mais perguntas.

Comment: Valew @Cigano, depois de um tempinho aquecendo as baterias acabei pegando no tranco. A validação acima é realizada quando do ModelState.isValid e está funcionando numa boa. Agora preciso refletir isso no formulário, via unobtrusive. Como você sugeriu, vou abrir outra pergunta com esse tema específico. []s